# Take image from array and set as backgroundimage of class in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an array **items** having three items, I have selected 2 items randomly one taken its label and displayed it in 2 boxes inside `<p>`.

`i want the URL of the selected item to be displayed as`**background image** `of the corresponding box.`, ie if 1 is displayed in the first box its background image should be URL of 1.

HOW TO ACHIEVE IT?? the image should fit inside the box.

I have to use the background-image st method but it's not working

```js
var array2 = [];
var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  }
];

array2 = items.slice();
rvalue();

var item;

function rvalue() {
  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length);
    item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    ptags[index].textContent = item[0].label;
    //boxes[index]style.backgroundImage = item.url; 

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
  }

}
```

```css
.box {
  width: calc(15.4% - 4px);
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #0F6;
}

.box {
  height: 15vh;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #005ce6;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 7 px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="box" id="10">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="11">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `url(link)` instead of `link` like :

```
boxes[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url('+item[0].url+')';
```

```js
var array2 = [];
var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  }
];

array2 = items.slice();
rvalue();

var item;

function rvalue() {
  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length);
    item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    ptags[index].textContent = item[0].label;
    boxes[index].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + item[0].url + ')';

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
  }

}
```

```css
.box {
  width: calc(15.4% - 4px);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #e6e600;
  margin: -2px;
  display: inline-flex;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #005ce6;
  text-align: center;
}

.text {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 7 px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

body {
  background-size: 100vw 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="box" id="10">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="11">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: it displayed th url onthe box, but iwant the image to be fully displayed on the box,

Comment: ie width should be equel to box width, and height should be equal to height

Answer (score 0):

In order that the image would fit to the box, you can add few css rules to the `box` class, and use `boxes[index].style.backgroundImage = "url("+ item[0].url +")"` to set the background image itself.

```js
var array2 = [];
var items = [{
    label: '1',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  },
  {
    label: '2',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  },
  {
    label: '3',
    url: 'https://picsum.photos/200/300/?random'
  }
];

array2 = items.slice();
rvalue();

var item;

function rvalue() {
  ptags = document.querySelectorAll('[name="values"]');
  boxes = document.getElementsByClassName("box");

  for (var index = 0; index < 2; index++) {
    var randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * array2.length);
    item = array2.splice(randomIndex, 1);

    ptags[index].textContent = item[0].label;
    boxes[index].style.backgroundImage = "url("+ item[0].url +")"

    ptags[index].dataset.itemIndex = randomIndex;
  }

}
```

```css
.box {
  width: calc(15.4% - 4px);
  height: 15vh;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #333;
  border: #000 border-color: #e6e600;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: -2px;
  background-color: #0F6;
  justify-content: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
}

#container {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-align: center;
  border: px solid #CC0000;
  margin: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
}

.box p {
  font-size: calc(2vw + 10px);
}

p {
  font: "Courier New", Courier, monospace;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: #005ce6;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">

  <div class="box" id="10">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="11">
    <p name="values"></p>
  </div>


</div>
```